# Random value in month column in datePicker in swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker

i'm getting random value month column.
for whatever value in choose in datepicker, value in month column remain same

Here is my code

```
@IBAction func chooseDobClicked(_ sender: Any) {

    self.view.endEditing(true)
    datePickerView.isHidden = false
    datePicker.isHidden = false
}

@objc func doDatePicker(){

    //DatepickerView
    self.datePickerView.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: Int(SCREEN_HEIGHT-280), width: Int(SCREEN_WIDTH-10), height: 276)
    self.datePickerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.datePickerView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    self.datePickerView.layer.masksToBounds = true
    self.datePickerView.layer.borderWidth = 2;
    self.datePickerView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor;

    doneBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(doneClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    doneBtn.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    doneBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 10, width: 80, height: 50)
    doneBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    doneBtn.backgroundColor = LogInVC.THEMECOLOR
    doneBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Raleway-Bold", size: 16.0)
    doneBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
    doneBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
    doneBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    doneBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1

    cancelBtn.addTarget(self, action:#selector(cancelClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
    cancelBtn.setTitle("Cancel",for: .normal)
    cancelBtn.frame = CGRect(x: SCREEN_WIDTH-110, y: 10, width: 80, height: 50)
    cancelBtn.setTitleColor(UIColor.white, for: .normal)
    cancelBtn.backgroundColor = LogInVC.THEMECOLOR
    cancelBtn.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Raleway-Bold", size: 16.0)
    cancelBtn.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
    cancelBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
    cancelBtn.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    cancelBtn.layer.borderWidth = 1

    // DatePicker    
    self.datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame:CGRect(x: 0, y: 90, width: Int(SCREEN_WIDTH-20), height: 200))
    self.datePicker?.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    self.datePicker?.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.date
    self.datePicker?.layer.masksToBounds = true
 //   datePicker.center = view.center

        datePickerView.addSubview(datePicker)
        datePickerView.addSubview(doneBtn)
        datePickerView.addSubview(cancelBtn)

        self.view.addSubview(datePickerView)
        datePickerView.isHidden = true;
}

@objc func doneClicked(){

    let dateFormatter1 = DateFormatter()
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

    var calendar = Calendar(identifier: .gregorian)

    var components: DateComponents? = calendar.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day], from: datePicker.date, to: Date())
    print("Difference in date components: \(components?.day ?? 0)/\(components?.month ?? 0)/\(components?.year ?? 0)")
    if (components?.year ?? 0) < 18 || (components?.year ?? 0) >= 90 {
        var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Alert!", message: "User age should be greater than 18 years and less than 90 years.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK", otherButtonTitles: "")
        alert.show()
        return
    }
    print(dateFormatter1.string(from: datePicker.date))

    dobTextField.text = dateFormatter1.string(from: datePicker.date)
    dobTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    datePickerView.isHidden = true
}

@objc func cancelClicked(){

    datePickerView.isHidden = true
    dobTextField.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

This is the value I get[image]

this "45" value in month column in coming every time
sometimes it changes into "35"
 but always different value in month field

If anyOne has idea, please share.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's not random. You are using the wrong date format, `mm` is **minute**, `MM` is month.

```
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

Please read [unicode.org: Dates](https://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for more information

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it the problem with this line, you are setting minutes instead of month.

```
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
```

It should be

```
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
```

For the date formate with the month, it will be MM(capital letters) and for the minutes it will be mm(small).

You can refer this [blog](http://nsdateformatter.com/) to get the idea about various Format strings you can try.

Hope it helps